# Embed SQL SERVER R2 in .net Desktop application as single setup

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

How can i embed "SQL SERVER EXPRESS WITH ADVANCE SERVICE" in my .net  desktop application as **single setup** with **sql authentication** and **deploy database with data** to client side

Comment: SQL server express and configuration as well as the install of your app would need to be handled by an installer like install shield.

Comment: how can i...any example ??

Comment: Start by looking at the install shield limited version for visual studio, it's free and a link can be found here http://learn.flexerasoftware.com/content/IS-EVAL-InstallShield-Limited-Edition-Visual-Studio